# Please try re-compiling or re-installing Nodejs

Tags: node.js

Have upgraded our server from `Ubuntu-18.04LTS to Ubuntu-20.04LTS` After OS upgrade when I'm trying to start a nodejs application, but I get the below errors.

```js
2021-11-14 10:48:01.641 - error: server-node-1: '[task-manager] 
Error: The module \'/home/blruser/mibs/node_modules/weak/build/Release/weakref.node\'\nwas 
compiled against a different Node.js version using\nNODE_MODULE_VERSION 57. 
This version of Node.js requires\nNODE_MODULE_VERSION 64. 
Please try re-compiling or re-installing\nthe module (for instance, using `npm rebuild` or `npm install`).\n    at Object.Module._extensions..node (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:807:18)\n    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:653:32)\n    
at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:593:12)\n    
at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:585:3)\n    
at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:692:17)\n    
at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:25:18)\n    
at bindings (/home/blruser/mibs/node_modules/bindings/bindings.js:81:44)\n    
at Object.<anonymous> (/home/blruser/mibs/node_modules/weak/lib/weak.js:7:35)\n    
at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:778:30)\n    
at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:789:10)\nWARN: uncaughtException be generated\n'
```

```
$ nodejs --version
v10.19.0
```

How do i re-compile without losing any existing application data? Please support. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not able to ask more info in comments. But have you tried deleting your `node_modules` directory and installing afresh using `npm install` or `yarn install`? This would not have any impact on your application data, rather just the node modules.

But if it's an electron project or similar, try running `npm i -D electron-rebuild`, following that do the above mentioned step.